# TFS 2010 is trying to run MsTest 2010 project under MSTest 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, mstest

I've got a CI build set up to build my solution and run my unit tests.  The solution is VS 2010.  My test project targets the 4.0 framework. And the 10.0 version of the Unit Test Framework is properly referenced.  If I run the tests locally in VS 2010, I have no issues.  However, when I run my CI build on the TFS server (which is TFS 2010), I get an error stating:

File not found: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe

This is the MSTest for VS 2008, and it's not installed on my TFS server.  I do have VS 2010 installed on my TFS server including the testing tools but TFS doesn't look for it.

My question: Why would TFS be attempting to use this version of MSTest to run the tests?  I can't find this path specified anywhere in any project, solution, or configuration on the server.

The solution and related projects began life as VS 2008 projects and were migrated to VS 2010.  These files were pulled into a fresh install of TFS 2010 and a new TFS project.  They were not migrated from a 2008 TFS server.

[Activity Log](http://www.hdri.net/Blog/file.axd?file=2011/6/ActivityLog.txt)

[Full Log](http://www.hdri.net/Blog/file.axd?file=2011/6/CAATS.log)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you upgrade from 2008 to 2010 (server, slns, projects, builds etc)?  Or was this a clean install and all aforementioned files were created in 2010?

Comment: Also, can you provide the build output log please so I can see where in the build it is failing.

Comment: I edited the original to include the requested additional details.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the logs, the problem is that MSTest is running here using the wrong version because you have a legacy assembly reference.

Make sure your unit test project and any other projects being executed for test have the correct assembly reference to the new mstest assembly.  I am guessing you either missed a reference or added in the new reference and forgot to remove the legacy one.

"I can't find this path specified anywhere in any project, solution, or configuration on the server."

Yeah, you wouldn't see the path anywhere- it will just exec based on what assembly is referenced into the unit test proj.

Comment: Can you tell me what in the logs makes you think this?  I've looked through every project and cannot find an errant reference to the previous version.

Comment: The fact that there was no other indication that you referenced it in incorrectly or otherwise during the step or another step.  Just the process of elimination.  If you copied all your tests into a new test proj and ran the build (of course with that test proj) I am betting you would not run into this issue and further prove that it is an assembly reference issue.  I would give that a shot next if you cannot find the legacy reference anywhere.  MSTest will use whatever assembly reference it finds so it is finding it somewhere...

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no legacy references.  I think the idea of creating a new test project and moving the tests over is probably the best approach.  If that works, I'll mark this response as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow-up on this because I eventually discovered what was causing my issue and it was not the answer given above.  We were referencing a third party assertion utility kind of like "Should" called "SoftwareApproach.TestingExtensions" in this project.  This dll was an older one and contained a reference to MSTest 9 (from VS 2008).  Because this dll referenced MSTest 9, it was causing this error on the build server, however, the test would run locally.  Frankly, not sure why it didn't complain locally as there was no binding redirect and VS 2008 is not installed.

However, updating to a build of the mentioned dll that instead referenced MSTest 10 resolved our issue on the build server.